# How to execute a setup from an application to update it?

Tags: visual-c++, background-process, batch-processing

I'am currently writing an application that has to search on a web site if an update exists for this application. If it is the case the application download a setup file (created with inosetup) and then execute it.

My application is written in C++. And I do not arrive to do this process. I'am trying to call the setup using system(). If the command is system("mysetup") I cannot obtain what I want because the setup cannot replace the exe (currently running). So, I have tried to use system("cmd /C mysetup"), system("cmd/C start /min mysetup"), system ("cmd /C start /min /separate mysetup") without success. In these cases, the fact to stop the application also stop the setup. So I suppose that the setup is considered as a child process.

I have seen in some posts that it might be possible to use execcl(). But this function is in unistd.h. And this library is a little bit to specific for my needs (I need to be able to run on virtualized windows).

So do you have a way to do what I want?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,
A colleague to me gave me the solution. As we are using QT a QProcess::startDetached does exactly what I want.